# Spring different beans for different consumers

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Suppose I have several components that depend on one service:

```java
public interface MyService { ... }

// in package1
@Component
public class Package1Component1 {
  @Autowired
  private final MyService myService;
}

public class Package1Component2 {
  @Autowired
  private final MyService myService;
}

// in package 2
public class Package2Component1 {
  @Autowired
  private final MyService myService;
}

public class Package2Component2 {
  @Autowired
  private final MyService myService;
}
```

And I have two implementations of `MyService`:

```java
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl1 implements MyService { ... }

@Service
public class MyServiceImpl2 implements MyService { ... }
```

And I want `MyServiceImpl2` to be injected into all components in package2 and `MyServiceImpl1` everywhere else

I don't want to use `@Qualifier` to resolve ambiguity as it will require to always specify it when you need to inject `MyService` and to change a lot of files when I need to switch to single implementation everywhere (`MyServiceImpl2` is temporary implementation that should be used only in specific scope).

Is there any way to specify bean for `scope` (java package?), like in Angular I can override module providers (`AuthService` in this case):

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent, UserInfoComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthService,
      useClass: FacebookAuthService,
    },
  ],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce your meta-annotation annotated with @Qualifier and use it.
Once you are ready to change, just change Qualifier on  your meta annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not really correct to co-relate Angular specificities with Spring, as they are simply two radically different infrastructures, in all aspects.

Why don't you want to use `@Qualifier`? for what reason? because, the problem you describe is exactly why people came up with `@Qualifier` implementation.

> I don't want to use @Qualifier to resolve ambiguity as it will require to always specify it when you need to inject MyService and to change a lot of files when I need to switch to single implementation everywhere.

Not really. You can provide ID for your bean definition, and disregarding of what implementation you'll use later, same bean, with that same ID, will be injected wherever you'll qualify it to be injected. You will only swap the implementation class.

Also, `package` in Java, is not a scope for Beans. Package is facility for grouping a logically similar classes, and it *can* be considered as a scope, but for class and its members' accessibility/visibility, not for the beans.

Bean scopes have a different semantics, and you can read about them [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes).

The is another way to specify, that the bean should qualify as a candidate, if there are more than one implementations of a type you're injecting. It's [`@Primary`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html); however, this `@Primary` will always override any other candidates, while with `@Qualifier` you can leverage more fine-grained control on what to inject where.

Comment: Once again about qualifiers: they break incapsulation and composability. I, as author of component, should not think about how my component will be used and what dependencies will be injected into it. With qualifiers, I, as an author of component, must be aware that there are multiple implementations of some dependency. But it breaks the idea that component is inidependent thing and it shouldn't know in which environment it is used. Just like in Angular, that is why I compare Angular DI with Spring DI.

Comment: I'm not sure you got the encapsulation concept right. Encapsulation is just *hiding* a level of implementation and providing an abstraction for that implementation. If you have two or more qualifying candidates, for one type, you should differentiate them, somehow.. otherwise, based on *what* criteria you want Spring to decide which one to inject? if you work with a case of inheritance, you can also declare field with a specific subtype, instead of a supertype.. this will also eliminate an ambiguity.